# The second svg statement will not render

Tags: html, svg

I believe this is a duplicate, but no matter what I do, it always fails to load the second pair of svg tags. EDIT: This would not display in code blocks or in the entire question correctly, so here it is:[Pastebin: SVG Error](https://pastebin.com/jiLwDp4A)

```
link : jiLwDp4A I'm not really sure what to put here, I just joined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate `id` attributes ("one" and "two"). Ids **must** be unique within a document.

Consider your `begin="0s; two.end"`. Which `<animate>` element with `id="two"` should the browser be using here?

Change the second SVG to use different `id` attributes.

Comment: *sigh* I changed the second one, but it still won't seem to work.   `<animate id="three" begin="0s; four.end" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="1000" to="0" dur="4s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate id="four" begin="three.end" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="1000" dur="4s" fill="freeze" />`

Comment: Then perhaps this wasn't the problem. Both SVGs work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/yr35sj9x/

Comment: Weird. Here's the full source. [View Source:](https://pastebin.com/mVh4Q8nq0) EDIT: The source works in js fiddle. Even without the javascript dependencies.

Comment: That pastebin link is broken.

Comment: That was embarrassing. Thanks for hanging in though. The link should work now. [View Source:](https://pastebin.com/mVh4Q8nq)

Comment: That HTML seems to work just fine. But the second SVG is not visible because it is off screen.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try moving it around a bit. I'll update here if i get results. EDIT: Sadly, it doesn't work, even when I move it around. Could you send me an example of my html file where it would work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the particles.js could block this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ozcbj25e/  I suppose it is possible. Obviously I don't have it so I am not loading it. You can answer that question yourself by removing it.

Comment: I had just saved your pastebin file to disc and loaded it in a browser. There the first SVG fills the page and the second one is shoved off the page bottom. It's hidden because of the `overflow: hidden` in your `<body>` tag. I suppose it could be particles.js causing problems but obviously I don't know because I don't have it. You can test that yourself by removing it.